# ¿Cómo cambiar de estado "activo" a "inactivo" automáticamente LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel

Necesito que el estado "activo" cambie automáticamente al estado "inactivo" cuando la fecha actual sea mayor a la fecha límite.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no sirve.

Este es el controlador.

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $conciertocontroller=new ConciertoController();
    $conciertocontroller->show();
}

public function show(){
    $validacion='Está en el else';
    $hoy=date('Y/m/d');
    $fechas=DB::table('concierto')->select('fecha')->get();
    $i=0;
    $c=count($fechas);
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
        if($fechas[$i]<$hoy){
            $concierto=new Concierto;
            $concierto->estado="Inactivo";
            $concierto->update();
        }else{
            dd($validacion);
        }
    }
}
```

Desde aquí lo llamo.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{url('banda/concierto')}}">          
      Conciertos
</a>
```

Esta es la ruta.

```
Route::resource('banda/concierto','ConciertoController');
```

Comment: Cómo piensas correr este código? con un cronjob? luego de alguna acción en específica? Detalla

Comment: Si. Este código se ejecuta cuando yo doy clic en una etiqueta <a>

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar fechas usa Carbon que ya viene incluido en Laravel:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ConciertoController extends Controller{

public function show(){
    $validacion='Está en el else';
    $hoy=date('Y/m/d');
    $fechas=DB::table('concierto')->select('fecha')->get();
    $i=0;
    $c=count($fechas);
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
        //Fecha actual:
        $fecha_actual = new Carbon;
        //Con las fechas límites de tu array de la BD(???) suponiendo que vienen en un formato por ejemplo 'Y-m-d'
        $fecha_bd = new Carbon($fechas[$i]);
        if($fecha_actual->gt($fecha_bd)){
            $concierto=new Concierto;
            $concierto->estado="Inactivo";
            $concierto->update();
        }else{
            dd($validacion);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Aquí](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) te dejo la documentación de Carbon, la función `gt()` de la clase Carbon quiere decir "greater than" y recibe como parámetro una instancia de la clase Carbon a comparar, entonces, como te darás cuenta la condición quiere decir: "si la fecha actual es mayor a la fecha de tu array de fechas de la BD..."